# CGAL Point_2 Polygon_set_2 Distance

Tags: polygon, distance, point, cgal

I've been searching google for a while now and I think I'm doing something wrong. As the title suggests, I'm logging for the cgal-way to determine the min distance of a Point_2 to a Polygon_set_2. Did I overlook something in the documentation? I did iterator over the edges of every polygon in the set to determine it "by hand" but that's awfully slow and doesn't exploit the arrangement of the Polygon_set_2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see is to locate the point in the underlying arrangement and then find the closest segment from the edges of the cell the point is located on.

See this [section](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#arr_secqueries) of the user manual and the corresponding [reference manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/group__PkgArrangement2PointLocation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll try that next. I'll use it for a 2d collision test so I hope it's fast :D